# Disable generation of metagen files in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clr

When I build a C++/CLI project I get, among others, a file called "proj.exe.metagen".

Deleting it does not impair the execution of the generated executable so I'd rather have it not generated unless there is a good reason to have it around.

How can I disable generation of the metagen file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Project > Properties > General > "Enable Managed Incremental Builds" setting.  That's for VS2015 and also for VS2010.

Everybody likes fast builds so the default is Yes.  If you select No then msbuild no longer needs the .metagen file to speed up the build and won't create it anymore.

The following image shows the setting in VS2010.

[image: Location of Enable Managed Incremental Build setting in VS2010]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is in the same place for VS2010. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to reflect it and added a picture.